# Application Insights (partially) missing data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to retrofit Application Insights into an existing app but no matter what I do, I can only seem to get telemetry back from the front end:

[image: Application Insights dashboard]

(note "Add Application Insights SDK..." banner, "No data" warning, apparently 0ms for all server responses and 0 server requests - the little blue semi-circle on server response times is just the current selected point)

I've installed v2.1.0 of the following nuget packages:

```
"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights"
"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept"
"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector"
"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget"
"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector"
"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web"
"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer"
"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel"
```

and added my instrumentation key to the ApplicationInsights.config file:

```
  <InstrumentationKey>{my key here}</InstrumentationKey>
</ApplicationInsights>
```

I've also monitored the events going through ETW and I see plenty of messages suggesting that data is getting logged although there are also quite a lot of messages saying:

```
WebTelemetryInitializerNotExecutedOnNullHttpContext
```

but not sure if that's a problem or not?

To confuse things a little further, *some* server-side data *does* seem to be getting through since the application map looks like this:

[image: Application Map]

I've also tried installing the Application Insights Agent on the box, but that made absolutely no difference that I could see!

There appear to be a number of similar questions out there, but they all seem to have no resolution, the resolution is to remove and re-add the nuget packages (tried) or there were multiple ApplicationInsights.config files (checked and there aren't)...

N.B. this app is usually running on a VM in AWS EC2, but there are no firewall rules blocking any outbound traffic and I've also tried running it locally...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working, but can't really explain.

Started again from scratch, and this time it worked, even though my initial attempt and starting from scratch last time didn't.

I noticed that there are some new features such as integration with Code Lens, so I don't know if something changed in Application Insights, or something went wrong twice in a row (though I don't know what **could** have gone wrong since adding Application Insights is not really a complicated process!)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem is the WebTelemetryInitializerNotExecutedOnNullHttpContext message you found. Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/blob/master/Src/Web/Web.Shared.Net/Implementation/WebTelemetryInitializerBase.cs), this means that the HttpContext.Current is null.

I'm not sure why this is happening in your case, so can you please elaborate on your web app structure? Are you running IIS on the VM?

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.NET projects please also consider the used azure region. There are problems with the "Germany West Central" region. It does not synchronizes all data to azure application insights. We solved our problem by switching the aplication insights azure instance to the region "Europe West" (We had no problems with ASP.NET CORE projects).

I have no idea why MS does not mention this fact, but after hours of searching we found the following github entry -> https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/1931

Comment: Can you please share what didn't work for Germany West Central? Referred issue in github might be irrelevant (at the time this region wasn't available, it was released in Public Preview only in October 2020).

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/services/?products=monitor&regions=us-central,us-east,us-east-2,us-north-central,us-south-central,us-west-central,us-west,us-west-2,europe-north,europe-west,germany-non-regional,germany-central,germany-north,germany-northeast,germany-west-central

Comment: This is a link to a status of Application Insights in Germany West Central

Comment: Right now this region should be fully functional. If you're facing issues with it - would be interested to learn more!

Comment: @ZakiMa We just verified the issue today and switched to europe west. For "Germany West Central" not all data like server response time, server request count where synced to our app insights azure instance. We then tried to setup an asp.net core application, where everything worked fine. I have no idea why it still does not work. At least not for the asp.net standard version. But by switching to different region we solved that issue. You could reproduce the error by setting up an asp.net mvc project based on msdn documentation. You won't get all data synced (e.g. server response time)

Comment: Thank you! Quick question - did you use instrumentation key or connection string?

Comment: I used the instrumentation key

Comment: I think it will start working with Connection String.

Comment: SDK doesn't expose it but if you use Fiddler you would see 308 response from this particular stamp: "Ingestion is allowed only from stamp specific endpoint - Location: https://germanywestcentral-0.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/v2/track"

Comment: I also tried the connection string acutally :) but did not work. One of my colleagues had a running application insights environment and he got the same issue, as soon as he switched to germanywestcentral. Our IT guy also stated, that this issues comes from the region issue stated in the github. Anyway, it fixed our problem after testing every possiblity using germany west central. Further more, the asp.net core version actually worked without a problem but not the asp.net standard.